# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs

Este es un componente funcional, basado en una función. Este tan solo pide los datos y los enlista en 'cards'. El componente 'Card' es el que tiene el código de presentación. Mas no sé si de este componente último venga el problema. Creo que se trata de alguna declaración o algo así.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

import Card from './Card'

function ExercisesList(props){
    <div>
    {
            props.exercises.map((exercise) => {
            return (
            <Card 
                title ={exercise.title}
                description ={exercise.description}
                colorBackground ={exercise.colorBackground}
                image ={exercise.image}
            />               
            )})
    }
    </div>
}

export default ExercisesList
```

Este es el código y el error que me muestra en el navegador es el siguiente:

```
Failed to compile
./src/Components/ExercisesList.js
  Line 6:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucioné. Al parecer olvidé el 'return' en la función principal que es ExercisesList. En conclusión el componente funcional necesitaba retornar algo